# Sci-fi book about people living in a giant bubble in space

Tags: story-identification

I read this book soon after it came out in the past 10 years or so.  It was set in a giant bubble in space with an artificial sun in the center.  There was no gravity but the bubble was full of air with small colonies built on rocks or wooden structures floating inside the bubble.

The author apparently had several novels that explored the same topic.

Comment: If you liked this, you might enjoy "[Look to Windward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_to_Windward)" by Iain M. Banks. It has an extensive sequence set inside an 'airsphere', basically a gigantic air-filled balloon in which enormous entities play host to smaller species.

Comment: You could try and add some more info, e.g. language you read it in, or where you read it (country), even describe the cover.

Comment: You could also go back to ringworld for an original take on the concept.

Answer (score 17):

Could this be "[Sun of Suns](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77887.Sun_of_Suns)" by Karl Schroeder?

> It is the distant future. The world known as Virga is a fullerene
>   balloon three thousand kilometers in diameter, filled with air, water,
>   and aimlessly floating chunks of rock. The humans who live in this
>   vast environment must build their own fusion suns and "towns" that are
>   in the shape of enormous wood and rope wheels that are spun for
>   gravity.

There were 5 books set in the same '[Virga](http://www.goodreads.com/series/40972-virga)' universe.

[image]

Comment: It's a pretty good series, too.  I knew what it was by the truncated description on the question list, but was just a shade too late (when I refreshed there were no answers, when I opened the question in full there already was one).

Answer (score 0):

This might be the short story "Mountain" (2015) by Liu Cixin:
https://www.apex-magazine.com/mountain/

From Goodreads:

> Some people enjoy mountain-climbing as a hobby, while others hate it. What if mountain-climbing had become something necessary for survival? A group of pitiful aliens are forced to exist within a small spherical space, surrounded by layer upon layer of rock. They have named this space the "Bubble World," and their lifelong ambition is to find out what might exist beyond the rock walls that envelop them. Do the strata just go on forever? Or could they end in a void? To this end they build great ships of exploration, dying generation after generation as they adventure outward. Consequently, they form a completely unique world view, as well as theories of physics and cosmology that are vastly different from our own.